# How to upgrade Jersey 2.2 to Glassfish 4?

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, glassfish-4

I've tried to upgrade the Jersey 2.2 to the Glassfish 4 by replacing the following jars at the `[gf_home]/glassfish/modules` with `version 2.2`

1. jersey-bean-validation.jar
2. jersey-client.jar
3. jersey-common.jar
4. jersey-container-grizzly2-http.jar
5. jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
6. jersey-container-servlet.jar
7. jersey-gf-cdi.jar
8. jersey-gf-ejb.jar
9. jersey-media-json-jackson.jar
10. jersey-media-json-jettison.jar
11. jersey-media-json-processing.jar
12. jersey-media-moxy.jar
13. jersey-media-multipart.jar
14. jersey-media-sse.jar
15. jersey-mvc-connector.jar
16. jersey-mvc-jsp.jar
17. jersey-mvc.jar
18. jersey-server.jar

After clearing the `[gf_home]/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache` and try to start the glassfish but there is no luck. Could you please help to advise further?

Comment: Do you see any exception?

Comment: There is an exception about the `hk2`. I've tried to update the `hk2` to the `version 2.2.0-b14`. It causes the another problem as well.

Comment: I see, Jersey 2.0 in GF 4.0.0 uses version `2.1.88` of `hk2` but we switched to `2.2.0-bx` in Jersey 2.1. The safest way would be to download nightly build of GF 4.0.1 as suggested by Mira.

Comment: In this article, there is a solution. http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-rs-20-and-jersey-20 see you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the approach you did is correct. The problem is that Glassfish 4.0 might not work with newest Jersey version as there might be incompatibilities. Jersey is used internally in Glassfish and when there is a problem with incompatible Jersey versions, Glassfish might not even start (like in your case).

You can try using one of the Glassfish night builds which have already Jersey 2.2 integrated.

http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/

The link is accessible from http://glassfish.org (Download->Work in progress). Night build versions might be unstable.

You can try for example build: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/glassfish-4.0.1-b02-08_22_2013.zip

Mira

#### EDIT 1

In the following article you can find a script that does the update of Jersey 2 in GlassFish 4.0.1 for you:

- [Updating Jersey 2 in GlassFish 4](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/01/21/updating-jersey-2-in-glassfish-4/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation. Since the `Glassfish 4.0.1` has not been released yet. Do we have an chance to use the `Jersey 2.2` within the `Glassifish 4.0.0`? Should I stick with the `Jersey 2.0`? Could you please help to advise further?

Comment: Latest 4.0.1 nightly build contains 2.4 Jersey with great improvement: it's possible to inject HttpServletContext in ContainerRequestFilter. http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip